# what Is Mainloop in the Godot game engine??

Tags: godot, godoc

I am a godot beginner. so i just needed help, if somebody can explain it a little bit and the OS thing. I am stuck. How does the mainloop work and how does it interact with the OS they state in godot doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MainLoop` is the, well, main loop of the program. It loops until the app is closed. In this loop it handles, delegates, and processes things such as input, rendering, audio, physics, and more.

`OS` is the api to the OS running the app. `OS` is the interface to the file system, input, system info, interrupts, app container, and more.

`MainLoop` uses `OS` for input, interrupts, initialization, and more.

Then `SceneTree` inherits `MainLoop` which adds on to that loop by managing your tree of nodes that make up your scene.

This is missing a lot of specifics and is not totally accurate, but I hope it helps.